# Regarding Object Comparison

Tags: java, class

I am having a java class Rec.  I have two instance of it Rec1 and Rec2. I want to check whether the values of Rec1 and Rec2 are equal. If i do Rec1.equals(Rec2) is it correct way of doing it?

```
class Rec {

  private BigDecimal  RecordId = null; 

  private BigDecimal recSubNum = null; 

  private BigDecimal  FileId = null;

  private String    Category = null; 

  private BigDecimal status = null; 

  private BigDecimal errorCode = null; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to implement object equality in Java:

```
class Rec {
  private BigDecimal recordId = null;
  private BigDecimal recSubNum = null;
  private BigDecimal FileId = null;
  private String category = null;
  private BigDecimal status = null;
  private BigDecimal errorCode = null;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int ret = 41;
    ret = hc(ret, recordId);
    ret = hc(ret, recSubNum);
    ret = hc(ret, fieldId);
    ret = hc(ret, category);
    ret = hc(ret, status);
    ret = hc(ret, errorCode);
    return ret;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (ob == null) return false;
    if (ob.getClass() != Rec.class) return false;
    Rec r = (Rec)ob;
    if (!eq(r.recordId, record)) return false;
    if (!eq(r.recSubNum, recSubNum)) return false;
    if (!eq(r.fileId, fileId)) return false;
    if (!eq(r.category, category)) return false;
    if (!eq(r.status, status)) return false;
    if (!eq(r.errorCode, errorCode)) return false;
    return true;
  }

  private static boolean eq(Object ob1, Object ob2) {
    return ob1 == null ? ob2 == null : ob1.equals(ob2);
  }

  private static int hc(int hc, Object field) {
    return field == null ? hc : 43 + hc * field.hashCode();
  }
}
```

**Note:** the equals/hashCode contract for Java means that for any two objects a and b:

```
a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)
```

and if two objects are equal then `a.hashCode()` must equal `b.hashCode()`.

**Edit:** there are two ways of checking if the types match. Either:

```
if (ob == null) return false;
if (ob.getClass() != Rec.class) return false;
```

or

```
if (!(ob instanceof Rec)) return false;
```

These two do different things and you should select the correct one depending on what you want to do. I generally prefer the first one unless you know you need the second. What's the difference?

```
class A {
  public int i;

  public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (!(ob instanceof A)) return false;
    return i == ((A)ob).i;
  }
}
```

Looks reasonable right? What if the class gets extended:

```
class B extends A {
  public int j;

  public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (!(ob instanceof B)) return false;
    if (!super.equals(ob)) return false;
    return j == ((B)ob).j;
  }
}
```

Still looks reasonable? It's broken.

```
A a = new A();
a.i = 10;
B b = new B();
b.i = 10;
b.j = 20;
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true! Is this really what you want?
System.out.println(b.equals(a)); // false! Different to previous = problem.
```

That's why I favour `getClass()` over `instanceof` unless I *really* want subclass equality.

Comment: @arav, here's a related article you might want to read: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17
@cletus +1 for the full answer :)

Comment: This works well, but the Apache EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder from apache lang http://commons.apache.org/lang/ make this trivial.

Comment: +1, cheers for that -- something I didn't know existed. Might be relevant to my interests in the future :)

Comment: The contract also includes that the two objects should be the same concrete class and that 
    o.equals(null) == false

The code in this comment will throw a NullPointerException if passed a null.

Apache EqualsBuilder and HashCodeBuilder do make it easy, but you still have to do the class match and null check.

Comment: Instead of calling `ob.getClass().equals(Rec.class)`, use `ob instanceof Rec` - this will return false if `ob` is null, instead of throwing the NullPointerException.

Comment: @rjohnston: there's a problem with `instanceof`. See the update.

Comment: @cletus that's really swapping one problem for another, but I can see how making `equals` fail for subclasses by default would be desirable. I was mainly concerned with your initial definition breaking the a.equals(null) part of the contract, which you've fixed now, so it's all good

Answer (score 0):

if Rec is a user defined class then you really should override the equals method otherwise it will just call the equals method in the Object class;

something like :

```
public boolean equals(Rec x){
    //check here to see if the references are the same, if so return true
    if(this == x) return true;

    //if they aren't the same object then check all the fields for equality
    if (category.equals(x.category) && etc etc) return true;
    else return false;
}
```