# Java override Object equals() method

Tags: java, generics, object

How do I override the equals method in the object class?

i.e I have

```
class Person{

//need to override here
public boolean equals (Object obj){

}
```

I want to convert the parameter obj to a type Person, but if I do (Person) obj it won't work.

Comment: Note you need to be careful if you have a non-final class. Typically you should check the runtime class with `obj.getClass() == Person` rather than `instanceof Person`. Although it is possible to write a contract that makes derived types equal (like `java.util.List`). Also you should override `hashCode` if you override `equals`, but that's probably getting ahead a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cast it inside the method, just make sure that is of the right type using instance of

```
if(obj instanceof Person)
{
   Person otherPerson = (Person) obj;
   //Rest of the code to check equality
}
else
{
//return false maybe
}
```

Comment: And I thought about Person otherPerson = (Person) obj;
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It's actually more complicated than you might think. Have Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using) auto-generate an `equals` method; you'll see it contains a few checks and casts before it does a comparison.

Also see here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

Answer (score 8):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) 
{
    if (o instanceof Person) 
    {
      Person c = (Person) o;
      if ( this.FIELD.equals(c.FIELD) ) //whatever here
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Lots I don't like about that code, but I am forced to +1 for `@Override`.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Regarding Object Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315836/regarding-object-comparison/2315850#2315850).

Be aware that if you override `equals()` you **must** also override `hashCode()`. The equals/hashCode contract is that if two objects are equal they must have the same hash code.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to create subclasses of Person, use something like

if(obj!=null && obj.getClass() == Person.class)

rather than instanceof

Comment: Why would one use getClass() instead of instanceof? (Just curious.)

Comment: e.g. if Employee extends Person ; and Employee has additional fields like id etc.
You may get a false positive using person.equals(employee)

Comment: It's not so much the false positives you need to worry about, but the **violation of reflexivity**.  Regardless of what you use, you can basically guarantee that `new Employee().equals(new Person())` is going to be false (Person is not an instance of Employee).  The result **must** be the same if you invert the arguments, so a Person **cannot** be equal to a subclass of itself (unless you do something very funky in the subclass' `equals()` method).

Comment: Additionally - I would prefer the example to read `if(obj!=null && obj.getClass() == this.getClass())` as this will work properly when inherited by subclasses.  The example in your answer at the moment would lead to an instance of a subclass not being equal to itself (unless it overrode equals()), which is also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use `getClass()` rather than `instanceof` is if one wanted to assert that both references being compared point to objects of the exact same class rather than objects implementing the same base class.

Say we have an `Employee` **e** and a `Manager` **m** (extends `Employee`).

`m instanceof Employee` would yield true, `m.getClass() == Employee.class` would return false.

In some cases the latter might be preferred, but rarely in case of comparison of instances in `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the simpler, null-safe(r) `Objects.equals` for any field type:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Person) {
        Person p = (Person) o;
        return Objects.equals(p.FIELD, this.FIELD);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more point may be good to know that after you override `equals()` method (and also `hashcode()`) method you can to compare two objects of same class like follows:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();

....

if ( p1.equals( p2 ) )

{
   // --- Two Persons are equal, w.r.t the fields you specified in equals method ---

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered, but in my travels I have found this the most efficient way to override the comparison of an object to make sure it happens the same globally:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Person && this.getSomeMagicalField().equals(((Person) o).getSomeMagicalField());
}
```

**or** if you are not comparing strings:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Person && this.getSomeMagicalField() == (Person) o).getSomeMagicalField();
}
```